# How to save the key and value of a constant in two different columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a constant hash that has languages and their ISO code. I use this constant in an admin view, where the admin can select the language and create a category. I would like to save the language name and its ISO in two different columns without having to do it manually.

This is my constant:

```
LANGUAGES = {
  'fr': 'Français',
  'en': 'Anglais',
  'es': 'Espagnol',
  'de': 'Allemand',
  'pt': 'Portugais',
  'it': 'Italien',
  'ja': 'Japonais',
  'zh': 'Chinois',
  'ru': 'Russe',
  'ar': 'Arabe'
}.freeze
```

And the select in my simple_form:

`= f.input(:source_language, collection: Category::LANGUAGES.map { |iso, name| [name, iso] })`

I would like to save the iso in a column named `iso` and the name in a column named `source_language`.

Is there a simple and elegant way to get the name of the selected language and save it in a different column than the iso?

Should I do it in my controller with a matching on the ISO?

Comment: BTW, you can use `fr: 'Français'` instead of `'fr': 'Français'` – the quotes around the keys are superfluous.

Comment: What you get when you select and submit form ? Add your form params

Comment: Thank for the recommandation @Stefan, I corrected it

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want to store the name alongside its code if you already have that mapping table? Isn't that information redundant?

Comment: @Stefan A category is a couple of languages (created by the admin). The user will able to chooses a language by it's name but I have to save the ISO, for the future, when we'll add some variations like `pt-BR`. Also, I will have to show the name very often so I would like to avoid having to go through the constant each time

Comment: _"avoid having to go through the constant each time"_ – that sounds like premature optimization. The constant will be loaded anyway and hash lookup is blazing fast.

Comment: When using hashes you don't actually go through the whole list until it finds the correct key. Instead it uses a lookup algorithm to handle lookups based on the key. eg. `LANGUAGES[:en]` When you need turn it around and try to lookup the ISO code based on the name it becomes a different story (with the current hash). You could also simplify the mapping command to `LANGUAGES.map(&:reverse)`.

Comment: Well, I didn't know ! Thank you for these precisions, I'm going to use the constant directly. :)

Comment: Why not just use the [Rails I18n API](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)? Seems like you are needlessly reinventing the wheel. Also you should note that the "new" hash syntax coerces the keys into symbols. So `{ 'foo' : 'bar' }` is actually equivelent to `{ :foo => 'bar' }` not `{ 'foo'  => 'bar' }`.

Comment: Another option is to create a model for the languages so you could do something like `category.language.iso` or `category.language.name` this also allows you to add more languages dynamically as admin.

Comment: @max Yes I finally did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to set *source_language* attribute, depending on your needs.

- Do you want to have the ability to set the *iso* and *source_language* attributes independent of each other? Then you might want to set the *source_language* attribute in the controller on create/update.

  ```
  # app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
  LANGUAGES = Category::LANGUAGES.stringify_keys.freeze

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    @category.source_language = LANGUAGES[@category.iso]

    if @category.save
      # ...
    end
  end
  ```
- The first model based alternative is simply creating a setter that will do this based on the *iso* attribute.

  ```
  # app/models/category.rb
  def set_source_language
    languages = LANGUAGES.stringify_keys
    self.source_language = languages[iso]          
  end
  ```

  Then in the controller you can change the line `@category.source_language = LANGUAGES[@category.iso]` from above into `@category.set_source_language` and drop the controller `LANGUAGES` constant.
- You could combine the above solution with an override of the *iso* attribute setter.

  ```
  # app/models/category.rb
  def iso=(iso)
    super
    set_source_language
  end
  ```

  In this case you can completely remove the line `@category.set_source_language` from your controller. Keep in mind that the *source_language* should not be permitted inside the *category_params* method.

  Keep in mind this may yield "unexpected" results at times. If you set the *iso* followed by the *source_language* you can set them separate of each other. While first setting the *source_language* followed by the *iso* overwrites the *source_language* value with the one an the hash.
- Another option is using a model callback to ensure that the *source_language* is correctly set.

  ```
  # app/models/category.rb
  before_save :set_source_language
  ```

  This will make sure that *source_language* is always correctly set before saving into the database. However this may also yield "unexpected" results. You have to keep in mind that before save this attribute is not set and can't be used (unless you call *Category#set_source_language* manually). After changing the *iso* attribute the *source_language* is not immediately changed, you must first call *Category#set_source_language* or save the instance to set the new *source_language*.

  You could use this together with the above point to create a more cohesive experience. When using this solution you can also remove the line `@category.set_source_language` from the controller.

Comment: Thanks for all these details! I finally used the constant and translated it with I18n, then I set in a data-attribute they keys with their translations to access to in my javascript. By this way, there will no problems if we have to translate the website because I'm using only ISO codes. I mark your answer because it's the thing what I originally wanted to do. :)

Comment: Yep, I have seen your comment under your question mentioning that you where going to use the constant. I was already to far into the answer, so I posted it anyway. In my opinion using the constant is better since you don't duplicate your data.

Comment: It will be useful for me in the future, or for someone else!